# How to properly grayscale bitmap on android to make the file lighter

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I'm trying to get the most out of compression and I need to make my image grayscale in order to make the file lighter. 
I found a function that makes image grayscale:

```
fun toGrayscale(bmpOriginal: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        val width = bmpOriginal.width
        val height = bmpOriginal.height

        val bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val c = Canvas(bmpGrayscale)
        val paint = Paint()
        val cm = ColorMatrix()
        cm.setSaturation(0f)
        val f = ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm)
        paint.colorFilter = f
        c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0f, 0f, paint)
        return bmpGrayscale
}
```

Then I save it with

```
try {
    FileOutputStream(filePathGrayScale).use { out ->
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

But the image size **increase!**

What exactly I'm doing wrong and how to make the thing correct?

Comment: @NatigBabayev this is a compression as is, but not doing grayscale

Answer (score 1):

```
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
```

You are saving the image with an compression quality of 100. This *maximizes* file size (and minimizes quality loss).

If you want to make the most of compression, pass a lower value here. There is no ideal value because it really depends on the image being compressed and the tolerable amount of artefacts. It's a trade-of between file size and image quality.

For some more reading about the quality level see:
[What quality to choose when converting to JPG?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30243/what-quality-to-choose-when-converting-to-jpg)
And some examples [1](http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-estq.php), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Sample_photographs)